# tow error in codeigniter: Cannot modify header & Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can convert $files contain to array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847541/how-can-convert-files-contain-to-array)

i save files 'url_helper.php' & 'MY_Session.php' with BOM but still there are errors following:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\xampp\htdocs\Siran-mehdi\system\helpers\url_helper.php:1)
Filename: libraries/MY_Session.php
Line Number: 46

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\xampp\htdocs\Siran-mehdi\system\helpers\url_helper.php:1)
Filename: libraries/MY_Session.php
Line Number: 46

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\xampp\htdocs\Siran-mehdi\system\helpers\url_helper.php:1)
Filename: libraries/MY_Session.php
Line Number: 46

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: admin/tour.php
Line Number: 80

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\xampp\htdocs\Siran-mehdi\system\helpers\url_helper.php:1)
Filename: libraries/MY_Session.php
Line Number: 46

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\xampp\htdocs\Siran-mehdi\system\helpers\url_helper.php:1)
Filename: helpers/url_helper.php
Line Number: 543
```

this line 80 in tour.php:

```
$files = $this->multi_upload->go_upload();
        $images = array();
        foreach ($files as $img) {  //this is line 80
          $images[] = $img['file'];
        }
        if ( ! $files )
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $this->upload->display_errors());
            redirect('admin/tour/insert_foreign');
        }
```