# how can convert $files contain to array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

How do I solve this error?

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: admin/tour.php
Line Number: 81
```

this is line 81:

```
$files = $this->multi_upload->go_upload();
        var_dump($files);
        $images = array();     
        foreach ($files as $img) {   //line 81
          $images[] = $img['file'];
        }
```

this my $files in top code:

```
function go_upload($field = 'userfile') {
        $CI =& get_instance(); 
        // Is $_FILES[$field] set? If not, no reason to continue.
        if ( ! isset($_FILES[$field]['name'][0]))
        {
            $CI->upload->set_error('upload_no_file_selected');
            return FALSE;
        } else
        {
            $num_files = count($_FILES[$field]['name']) -1;
            $file_list = array();
            $error_hold = array();
            $error_upload = FALSE;
        }

        // Is the upload path valid?
        if ( ! $CI->upload->validate_upload_path())
        {
            // errors will already be set by validate_upload_path() so just return FALSE
            return FALSE;
        }

        for ($i=0; $i < $num_files; $i++) {

//            $fname = $_FILES[$field]['name'][$i];
//            echo "$fname\n\n<br><br>\n\n";

            $error_hold[$i] = FALSE;

            // Was the file able to be uploaded? If not, determine the reason why.
            if ( ! is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'][$i]))
            {
                $error = ( ! isset($_FILES[$field]['error'][$i])) ? 4 : $_FILES[$field]['error'][$i];

                switch($error)
                {
                    case 1:  // UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_file_exceeds_limit';
                        break;
                    case 2: // UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_file_exceeds_form_limit';
                        break;
                    case 3: // UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL
                       $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_file_partial';
                        break;
                    case 4: // UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE
                       $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_no_file_selected';
                        break;
                    case 6: // UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_no_temp_directory';
                        break;
                    case 7: // UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_unable_to_write_file';
                        break;
                    case 8: // UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_stopped_by_extension';
                        break;
                    default :
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_no_file_selected';
                        break;
                }

                return FALSE;
            }

            // Set the uploaded data as class variables
            $CI->upload->file_temp = $_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'][$i];
        $CI->upload->file_name = $_FILES[$field]['name'][$i];
            $CI->upload->file_size = $_FILES[$field]['size'][$i];        
            $CI->upload->file_type = preg_replace("/^(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $_FILES[$field]['type'][$i]);
            $CI->upload->file_type = strtolower($CI->upload->file_type);
            $CI->upload->file_ext  = $CI->upload->get_extension($_FILES[$field]['name'][$i]);

            // Convert the file size to kilobytes
            if ($CI->upload->file_size > 0)
            {
                $CI->upload->file_size = round($CI->upload->file_size/1024, 2);
            }

            // Is the file type allowed to be uploaded?
            if ( ! $CI->upload->is_allowed_filetype())
            {
                $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_invalid_filetype';
            }

            // Is the file size within the allowed maximum?
            if ( ! $CI->upload->is_allowed_filesize())
            {
                $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_invalid_filesize';
            }

            // Are the image dimensions within the allowed size?
            // Note: This can fail if the server has an open_basdir restriction.
            if ( ! $CI->upload->is_allowed_dimensions())
            {
                $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_invalid_dimensions';
            }

            // Sanitize the file name for security
            $CI->upload->file_name = $CI->upload->clean_file_name($CI->upload->file_name);

            // Remove white spaces in the name
            if ($CI->upload->remove_spaces == TRUE)
            {
                $CI->upload->file_name = preg_replace("/\s+/", "_", $CI->upload->file_name);
            }

            /*
             * Validate the file name
             * This function appends an number onto the end of
             * the file if one with the same name already exists.
             * If it returns false there was a problem.
             */
            $CI->upload->orig_name = $CI->upload->file_name;

            if ($CI->upload->overwrite == FALSE)
            {
                $CI->upload->file_name = $CI->upload->set_filename($CI->upload->upload_path, $CI->upload->file_name);

                if ($CI->upload->file_name === FALSE)
                {
                    $error_hold[$i] = TRUE;
                }
            }

            /*
             * Move the file to the final destination
             * To deal with different server configurations
             * we'll attempt to use copy() first.  If that fails
             * we'll use move_uploaded_file().  One of the two should
             * reliably work in most environments
             */
            if ( ! @copy($CI->upload->file_temp, $CI->upload->upload_path.$CI->upload->file_name))
            {
                if ( ! @move_uploaded_file($CI->upload->file_temp, $CI->upload->upload_path.$CI->upload->file_name))
                {
                     $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_destination_error';
                }
            }

            /*
             * Run the file through the XSS hacking filter
             * This helps prevent malicious code from being
             * embedded within a file.  Scripts can easily
             * be disguised as images or other file types.
             */
            if ($CI->upload->xss_clean == TRUE)
            {
                $CI->upload->do_xss_clean();
            }

            if ($error_hold[$i]) {
                $error_upload = TRUE;

//                echo $error_hold[$i];
            } else {
                if ($imageVar = $this->multiple_image_properties($CI->upload->upload_path.$CI->upload->file_name)) {

                    $file_list[] = array(
                            'name' => $CI->upload->file_name,
                            'file' => $CI->upload->upload_path.$CI->upload->file_name,
                            'size' => $CI->upload->file_size,
                            'ext' => $CI->upload->file_ext,
                            'image_type' => $imageVar->image_type,
                            'height' => $imageVar->height,
                            'width' => $imageVar->width
                            );
                } else {
                    $file_list[] = array(
                            'name' => $CI->upload->file_name,
                            'file' => $CI->upload->upload_path.$CI->upload->file_name,
                            'size' => $CI->upload->file_size,
                            'type' => $CI->upload->file_type,
                            'ext' => $CI->upload->file_ext,
                            );
                }
            }

// For debugging
/*            
            if (strlen($error_hold[$i]) > 1) {
                    print_r($error_hold);
            }
*/            
        } // end for loop

// Add error display for individual files        
        if ($error_upload) {
            $this->set_error($error_hold);
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return $file_list;
        }    
    }
```

Comment: You might want to `var_dump($files)` after `$files` is set. It's probably not an array or similar.

Comment: You should save WITHOUT BOM, first. Then, var_dump $files and see if it's an array as it should be

Comment: what $files looks like. The error says it's not an array

Comment: what did you get when you print_r($files) ? -)

Comment: what is the output of var_dump($files) ? Only after that we can help you

Comment: What does `var_dump($files);` returns? The large part of you code is not necessary at all, however it shows that you don't do much error checking.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that `$files` is not an array. `foreach` only works on arrays. We don't know what the value is, but in any case, it's not right. You'd have to look at the `go_upload` function to see why it's not doing what you expect.

Comment: I do not understand, please call for more.

Comment: @Martin. `$files` is not an array. I don't know why, but `$this->multi_upload->go_upload()` is returning something which isn't an array. Without any extra information, this is all I can really say. You'll have to look at the source of that function to find out more.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you get an array? is see several return FALSE. So you should check,

```
if ($files !== FALSE)
```

or casting it to an (empty) array (if false returns) with

```
$files = (array) $this->multi_upload->go_upload();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually doing like this you wil get the file or the value you want to.

```
foreach ($files as $img) {   //line 81
  echo $img; // echo the Var and you will see..
}
```

This line -> `$files = $this->multi_upload->go_upload();` probably come from a file object in your form, right? Then it must to be named like this `file[]` and not only `file`. You need to be specific that it is an Array. Otherwise nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Too avoid seeing this warning message you should count the array:

```
if (count($files) > 0)
{
    foreach ($files as $img) {   //line 81
        $images[] = $img['file'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' error this is probably because $files is not an array (or similar). The best way to do this IMHO is:

```
    $files = $this->multi_upload->go_upload();

    echo '<pre>';
    echo "Files:\n";
    print_r($files);
    echo '</pre>';

    $images = array();
    foreach ($files as $img) {  //this is line 80
      $images[] = $img['file'];
    }
    if ( ! $files )
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $this->upload->display_errors());
        redirect('admin/tour/insert_foreign');
    }
```

Please make this change and show us the output.

Comment: what output do you get? Even if $files is empty you should be getting 'Files:' being shown.

Comment: output is same error top post. please go to this address: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856670/problem-with-multi-upload-file-in-codeigniter , help me here. i putting full code...

Answer (score 0):

I figure I would just share how I handle multiple uploads in CI, it's a little different than your method:

Form looks like this:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/multiple_upload');?>
<input type="file" name="userfile[]" size="20" /><br />
<input type="file" name="userfile[]" size="20" /><br />
</form>
```

Upload/multiple_upload function in controller looks like this:

```
function multiple_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './userpics/originals/'; // server directory
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; // by extension, will check for whether it is an image
    $config['max_size']    = '512'; // in kb
    //$config['max_width']  = '1024';
    //$config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('myupload');
    $error = array(); $data = array();
    for ($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);$i++) {
            $this->myupload->initialize($config);
            if (!$this->myupload->do_upload('userfile',$i)) {
                    $error[] = $this->myupload->display_errors();
            }
            $data[$i] = $this->myupload->data(); //gradually build up upload->data()
    }

    if ( count($error) > 0 )        
    {
        print_r($error);
    }    
    else
    {
        print_r($data);
    }
}
```

At this point I made a copy of CI upload class, and pasted it into my applications library directory. A few changes need to be made. I named it myupload.

@ Line 143:

```
public function do_upload($field = 'userfile')
```

change to

```
public function do_upload($field = 'userfile', $i = 0)
```

Any lines in this function above line 200, you must add [$i] to the end of the $_FILES variables.

Example:

```
is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'])
```

change to:

```
is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'][$i])
```

There are 9 lines to be updated.

Comment: thank, why output several times info file(repeat), i only upload twice with tow file `banana63.gif, Untitled-159.gif`. if i want only output name file no all info, how is it?
like:`banana63.gif, Untitled-159.gif`